# DocuSign Connect update XML desserialization error

Tags: xml-parsing, docusignapi

I have been using DocuSign SOAP and REST based API calls to create envelope and am also using their Connect feature to update the recipient and envelope statuses for my clients.

I am getting a strange error parsing DocuSign Connect update for one client.
The error says "There is an error in XML document (1, 16174)".

Here is my code...

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(Request.InputStream)
 Dim reader As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xml))
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(DocuSignEnvelopeInformation), "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")

                    If Not serializer Is Nothing Then

                        envelopeInfo = TryCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)                            

                    Dim envid As String = envelopeInfo.EnvelopeStatus.EnvelopeID.ToString
```

I have tried bunch of things such as removing the XML definition from the XML document but did not work. The strange thing is that the same code works for all of my other clients. This is the only client that is having issues. They have added closed 65 tags in the document to be signed but I don't think that the tags are causing issues on their end since I also tried removing them.

Please advise.

Minal

Comment: Have you run the XML payload through any other validation script/app? It would be interesting to see if perhaps there is some client/signer entered data or tab/template specific setup that is triggering this.

Comment: To help isolate the issue I suggest testing with another document if you can. If the second document works it points to a specific issue with the first document, most likely an issue with the encoding.  If they both fail then I try going into your account preferences and enabling Request Logging.  Then run the code again and examine the logs.

Comment: @Ergin, I tried using another document but am getting the same error. I also enabled Request Logging and have created another envelope. The XML request looks fine.

Comment: @Ergin, I narrowed down the issue. The issue is related to the "SingerAttachmentOptional" tag that we are using in the envelope. The error states that the "SignerAttachmentOptional' is not a valid value for TabTypeCode.". We are able to create the envelope fine and it gets created with the SignerAttachmentOptional tag but while we are parsing the XML posted by DocuSign, we get an error during deserializing the XML.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this issue before when there are unsupported characters in the tab values or in the PDF byte stream itself when it is decoded. I suspect that copying and pasting values into tabs from external programs like Word introduce some invisible weird characters like  - carriage returns and the like. You should validate your XML in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I validated my XML and there are no errors in the XML file.